# How can we generate Handlebars file with html tags and data?

Tags: java, handlebars.js

We are using `hbs`(handlebars) formatted template on the backend side of the project for generate pdf file. What I want is this. Is there an option to create the hbs file with the data in it when the file is created? For example the hbs file in the following should be like this:

hbs before creation

```
<h4>address1:{{address1}}</h4>
<h4>address2:{{address2}}</h4>
<h4>city:{{city}}</h4>
<h4>state :{{state}}</h4>
```

hbs after creation

```
<h4>address1:value</h4>
<h4>address2:value</h4>
<h4>city:value</h4>
<h4>state :value</h4>
```

Comment: I am a little confused. First, why would the file be a Handlebars one if all of the Handlebars expressions (`{{ }}`) have been replaced?

Comment: It's normal to be confused. I want html codes and data to be formed in the hbs file, not the file. anyway at the end of the time of processing pdf generating.